# C# Winforms pictureBox vs ImageList in different forms

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I am trying to provide the picture from a PictureBox to another form in C# WinForms by if statement. To be more concrete, if I choose a pic from an image list and its count number is 1, I want to provide that picture to another form and its name (by manual writing), all that when I click a button. Here's my code, please be patient and help me to fix it. I don't have any errors, the program is working perfectly, but I have this bug, the pictures and the text doesn't appear on the other form. Have a great day!!!

Remarks: cakeChoose_pic, prajituri_pic are PictureBoxes

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(cakeChoose_pic.Image==imageList1.Images[1])
            {
                Comanda comanda = new Comanda();
                this.Hide();
                comanda.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
                comanda.Show();

                comanda.prajituri_pic.Image = imageList1.Images[1];
                comanda.prajitura_txtBox.Text = "Amandina";
            }


        }
```

Comment: I think you can try in different way,
Sending the image and string from Form1 to Form2 in parameters
Comanda comanda = new Comanda(Image, String);
Then in form2 change it in the Load method

Comment: There's quite a few bad practices in that code

Comment: Does the other form, "comanda", actually display?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: We need more information to be able to troubleshoot this.  Maybe show a video or GIF of the primary form display the secondary form on that button click?